# div and table siblings with similar CSS are positioned differently

Tags: html, css

I have a `table` and a `div` that should be displaying with the same width and at the same left position.

However, the table is being pushed right by something.  It's not showing up in Firebug, and I can't figure out what could be causing it.

I'll attach pictures of the Firebug console rather than copying all the code here.

This is the div that's aligned **as it should be**:
[image: image of the div]

This is the table that is bumped to the right:
[image: image of the table]

In case it might be an issue, the CSS for `#content` is:

```
#content {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

div {
    position: relative;
}
```

The CSS for `#page` is:

```
#page {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: -moz-use-text-color #C5CAE8;
    border-left: 0.0625em solid #C5CAE8;
    border-right: 0.0625em solid #C5CAE8;
    border-style: none solid;
    border-width: medium 0.0625em;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 30.5em;
    padding: 3em 0;
    width: 64em;
}

.clear {
    display: block;
}

div {
    position: relative;
}
```

I can post the CSS for more parents if necessary.

I've copied the code [to this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/EakVz/), and the problem is evident.

Comment: @mu is too short Yes, I've copied all of the HTML and CSS [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/EakVz/) and it displays with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is due to your `<div id="image"></div>` It is what is pushing your table to the right because the div is too high. If you make it smaller or remove it your table shifts all the way to the left. If you then remove the `position:relative` from your `table` style you have your desired result.

**Disclaimer:** only tested in Chrome 12 :)

Comment: This was right.  I've been meaning to fix that div height; I knew it was going to come back and bite me.  Gah.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem in Safari in your jsfiddle.net example. Try adding `overflow: hidden` to the

```
<div class="gutter message-box center w75 alert">
```

block. That makes that `<div>` and the `<table>` underneath line up for me. But the pair don't line up with the header. But, if you remove the `center` class from both the `<div>` and the `<table>`, everything starts to line up properly. I suspect that you had a combination of a float problem (hence the `overflow: hidden` trick) and some fighting margins (which killing `center` fixed).

I still see a small width problem with the `<table>` but the above should get you started.

Comment: Any idea what's causing this?  I added `.clear` to see what that did, and the message box doubled in height (and fixed the offset, too).  Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: @rockerest: There's a lot of unfamiliar HTML and CSS there so I guessed that there was a float problem based on the presence of a very short `<div>`. Removing `center` was also another guess. I'm old school, I hand craft all my HTML and CSS so I usually know exactly what's going on with my own stuff :)

Comment: The header is left aligned and the body content is centered.  That was a trick in itself.  On an almost identical site, the logo dropped below the header bar [as with this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513067/enforce-a-min-margin-for-a-fluid-layout).  I removed the margin on the wrapper that keeps it from sliding left in **this** implementation, so the wrapper just has `margin: auto`.  For what it's worth, this is all hand-coded, too, I just can't figure out what's causing it.

Comment: @rockerest: You could start removing things until the problem goes away. Or start from nothing and add things until it appears.

Comment: +1 cause of all the help!  I switched the answer to @joostschouten cause that's the real fix I was looking for :)  Thanks for all your time and knowledge.

Comment: @rockerest: No worries, that was nice find on joostschouten's part so I gave him an upvote too.